# How to set custom path for javax websockets using wildfly

Tags: java, websocket, wildfly, war

I was wondering if it was possible to set a custom URI path and port number linked to the @ServerEndpoint annotation.

At the moment the websocket can be opened on the following path once the wildfly server has been started.

ws://localhost:8080/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT/wstest

where test-1.0-SNAPSHOT seems to be the artifactID and version specified in the POM.

what I would like it to be opened on is

ws://localhost:8025/custom-path/wstest

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not speak too much about the solution that imply to setup a reverse proxy in front of you wildfly server in order to do whatever you want (listen multiple port, map one URL to another one ...)

Wilfly deploy application (usually war, but can be war inside ear). Those war are deployed inside context ( /test-1.0-SNAPSHOT in your example). This context is usually the name of the war file you use (or a name defined in application.xml in the ear file if you use ear).
You can update it by adding a `WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml` file in the war file. The content look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee">
   <context-root>/myContext</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

For the port, as every servers, wilfly listen to a port (default 8080). On the management console, you can find it, and modify it (or adding another listener).

But even if you set multiple listener, you will not be able on a single instance to listen to WS on one port, and HTTP on another. Both port will do everything.

And one application can only be deployed on a single context. If you don't want a context, you can deploy on the root context ("/") but it can become tricky if you deploy other application on the same instance.